# Discord py условия

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Вот мой код команды mute, мне бы хотелось, чтобы в случае, если пользователь не указывал время, бот сообщал об этом, но он просто не реагирует. Не могу понять, в чём ошибка и как её исправить

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time):
    muted_role=discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
    time_convert = {"s":1, "m":60, "h":3600,"d":86400}
    tempmute= int(time[0]) * time_convert[time[-1]]
    await member.add_roles(muted_role)
    if time is None:
        ctx.send('Вы не указали время!')
    else:

        embed = discord.Embed(description= f"✅ **{member.display_name}#{member.discriminator} успешно замьючен!**", color=discord.Color.green())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await asyncio.sleep(tempmute)
        await member.remove_roles(muted_role)
        embed = discord.Embed(description=f"✅ **У пользователя {member.display_name}#{member.discriminator} был снят мут!**",
                      color=discord.Color.green())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if time is None:
    ctx.send('Вы не указали время!')
```

Нужно поставить в начало функции. Т.к. бот использует `time` до этой проверки, то он просто выдаёт ошибку и завершает выполнение функции. + нужно добавить `return`:

```
if time is None:
    ctx.send('Вы не указали время!')
    return
muted_role=discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
time_convert = {"s":1, "m":60, "h":3600,"d":86400}
tempmute= int(time[0]) * time_convert[time[-1]]
...
```